# Azure LogicApp OneDriver trigger not working for large files (>50mb)

Tags: azure-logic-apps, onedrive

I have a azure logic app where the trigger is a OneDriveForBusiness connector that is watching for files to be created in a onedrive folder. Normally this works fine. However for large files (narrowed down to 52,397,814 works, 52,590,945 doesn't) the trigger never fires and shows as "skipped" in trigger history.

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Any suggestions as to a better place to ask about this?

My current plan is to switch to using a ZIP'd file... but I'm unhappy that there's an unknown upper limit after which file creates are ignored.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedriveforbusiness/#known-issues-and-limitations):

> The `When a file is created` or `When a file is modified` triggers will
> skip every file bigger than 50 MB.

Depending on your requirements, you either need to find another way of signalling that a file has been created, or you can run the Logic App by schedule and check if new files appeared, or you need to change the approach altogether.